# Javascript poor animation performance when many elements are on the DOM

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, animation, rendering

They say that if you update compositor only css properties (like transform translate), you will have good rendering performance because the engines can skip style calculations and do just the layer compositions. In [this test](https://glmachado.com/ani) I have 30K colored divs on the screen, and draging the red square has very poor performance.

Recording with the devtools I can see that I spend a lot of time with "system"

[image]

using chrome://tracing/ I can see that most time is being spent here

[image]

I could find some information on [chrome docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/graphics/paint/README.md) about this, it says

`PaintArtifactCompositor::Update is expensive and can be avoided for simple paint changes where layerization is known to not change. For example, if the color of a display item changes in a way that does not affect layerization, we can just update the display items of the existing cc::Layers. This is implemented in UpdateRepaintedLayers.`

It looks like chrome is checking those 30K divs to see if it can skip their drawing, and it looks like it skips them, since I see very small painting time, but this checking is taking too much time, it seems to me that it could be possible to tell chrome that it does not need to check those guys.